# Google Sheets Random Copy and Sort with Scripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I'm attempting to do is copy a column over and re-sort it. Problem is, it captures all available cells and uses the same space to re-sort, causing blank spaces. The idea is to create tournament match pairings, with the first column being the Roster itself, and following columns being players they will be matched against.

I'd also like to add a line that verifies a name doesn't appear twice on the same row, reshuffling until the column is all unique along each row

This is the code I have so far. I attempted to filter the data by swapping

```
  range2.setValues(shuffleArray(range.getValues()));
```

for

```
  range2.setValues(shuffleArray(range.getValues().filter(String)));
```

but this results in a "Number of data rows is 10 when range is 41" error, not verbatim obviously. I'm trying to collapse the blank spaces that are shown in this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXt4m.png).

I'm sure I can figure out how to expand it by however many matches I wish to generate.

```
function shuffleRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SETUP');
  var range = sheet.getRange('A31:A')
  var range2 = sheet.getRange('C31:C');
  range2.clearContents;
  range2.setValues(shuffleArray(range.getValues()));
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
  var i, j, temp;
  for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}
```

EDIT::::: Code has been moved to a test sheet hence different name and ranges, ive adjusted the samples when i moved them of course

```
function shuffleRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet4');
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:A40')
  var v = range.getValues().filter(String);      
        
      //Match 1
  var values = shuffleArray1(v);
  while (v.length != [...new Set(values.map(([a]) => a))].length) {
    values = shuffleArray1(v);  
  }
  range.offset(0, 1, values.length).setValues(values);

      //Match 2
  var values2 = shuffleArray2(v);
  while (v.length != [...new Set(values2.map(([a]) => a))].length) {
    values = shuffleArray2(v);  
  }
  range.offset(0, 2, values.length).setValues(values2);
}

function shuffleArray1(array) {
  var i, j, temp;
  for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

function shuffleArray2(array) {
  var u, v, temp;
  for (u = array.length - 3; u > 0; u--) {
    v = Math.floor(Math.random() * (u+2));
    temp = array[u];
    array[u] = array[v];
    array[v] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that `range2.clearContents` might be `range2.clearContent()`.
- In your script, by `sheet.getRange('A31:A')`, all rows in the sheet are retrieved.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about modifying `shuffleRange()` as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
function shuffleRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SETUP');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A31:A' + lastRow);
  var range2 = sheet.getRange('C31:C' + lastRow);
  range2.clearContent();
  var values = shuffleArray(range.getValues()).filter(String);
  range.offset(0, 2, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

- I'm not sure about the last row of your sheet. So, I proposed the above modification.

### Added 1:

From your following new question,

> essentially if the row contains a duplicate it has to reshuffle until each row contains a unique name from the original column, to create unique match pairings for tournaments, this will check the whole row, as some tournaments run only 2 matches, some up to 21

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function shuffleRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SETUP');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A31:A' + lastRow);
  var range2 = sheet.getRange('C31:C' + lastRow);
  range2.clearContent();
  var v = range.getValues().filter(String);
  var values = shuffleArray(v);
  while (v.length != [...new Set(values.map(([a]) => a))].length) {
    values = shuffleArray(v);
  }
  range.offset(0, 2, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

- In this case, when the duplicated values are included in `values`, `shuffleArray` function is run again.

### Added 2:

From your following reply,

> Unfortunately it produced duplicate lines almost immediately once i duplicate the functions to create a second set of results

> I added a new sample so you can see how im trying to expand it across several columns of results, this will create a set number of matches. I will, when done, swap the counter for a cell check so a user can set the match number, but thats later

#### Sample script:

```js
function shuffleRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SETUP');
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:A40');
  var v = range.getValues().filter(String);

  var createValues = v => {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // I'm not sure whether this line is required.
    var temp = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 40, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var existValues = temp[0].map((_, c) => temp.map(r => r[c]).join("")).filter(String);
    var values;
    do {
      values = shuffleArray1(v);
      while (v.length != [...new Set(values.map(([a]) => a))].length) {
        values = shuffleArray1(v);
      }
      var check = values.map(([a]) => a).join("");
    } while (existValues.some(e => e == check));
    return values;
  }

  var values1 = createValues(v);
  range.offset(0, 1, values1.length).setValues(values1);

  var values2 = createValues(v);
  range.offset(0, 2, values2.length).setValues(values2);
}
```

- In this modification, the new column values are created by checking all existing columns.

Comment: I replaced the last row variable with the actual last row, as its a fixed range due to max players, I just figured leaving it open would help condense.

You are 100% right I did mean clearContent()

adjusting the last row does exactly what i needed on the issue, it now compacts properly, thank you !

Comment: Just remembered to do that! Thanks! Do you know if theres an argument in the setvalues i can add to ensure each column I run this across doesnt have duplicates along each row?

Comment: @Tweak Thank you for your response. About your new question of `Do you know if theres an argument in the setvalues i can add to ensure each column I run this across doesnt have duplicates along each row?`, I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. The argument of `setValues` is only one. In your new question, what do you want to do? For example, do you want to remove the duplicated values?

Comment: essentially if the row contains a duplicate it has to reshuffle until each row contains a unique name from the original column, to create unique match pairings for tournaments, this will check the whole row, as some tournaments run only 2 matches, some up to 21

Comment: @Tweak Thank you for replying. About your new question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Comment: no need to apologize. Unfortunately it produced duplicate lines almost immediately once i duplicate the functions to create a second set of results

Comment: I added a new sample so you can see how im trying to expand it across several columns of results, this will create a set number of matches. I will, when done, swap the counter for a cell check so a user can set the match number, but thats later

Comment: @Tweak Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience again. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your actual goal, I apologize again.

Comment: No need for apology at all! You all on this thread have been very helpful and I am grateful!. Between your comment and another I managed to put together something. I realized that by shuffling the ENTIRE list I was already, effectively, giving each player 2 games, as they would appear twice, against unique opponents. Again, thank you for all your help :) I think when it comes to having more than 2, I may need a different function that splits the roster into 2 data sets for sorting and matching

Comment: @Tweak Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Tanaike's suggestion I've joined your two functions in order to be able to re-shuffle. I'm not as well-versed in coding, and probably there's a more-alike version of your code that also enables the re-shuffling. But you can try this:

```
 function shuffleRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SETUP');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var range = sheet.getRange('A31:A' + lastRow);
  var range2 = sheet.getRange('C31:C' + lastRow);
  range2.clearContents;
      function shuffleArray() {
        var i, j, temp;
        var array = range.getValues()
        var array2 = range.getValues()
        var count= 1;
        while (count>0){
          count=0
          for(i=array.length-1;i>0;i--){
            j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
            temp = array2[i];
            array2[i] = array2[j];
            array2[j] = temp;
          }

            for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
             if(array[i].toString() == (array2[i]).toString()){count = count+1}
            }}
        return array2
      }

  range2.setValues(shuffleArray())
}
```

I've make it try tenths of times and never got a duplicate:

[image]

Comment: how did you get that to span out across many columns, copying the code into mine, and adjusting it on my test sheet only produces one result column? Attempting to duplicate the function into its own (shuffleArray2, onto a new range called range3) does produce duplicates

Comment: That span was just for testing issues, and are only compared with the Column in A, it was just for showing that there were no duplicates with the original value. You can see it in this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y0bh0FBhVRf2aTtcCEhmSZrMW9ZySaNAOW_UdoshMCA/edit#gid=0) and test it with spans just change c>40 with other number if you want more tests. It has a conditional formatting in B31:38 that gets green when there is a match (see it in B that was manually entered

Comment: Do you need more columns and no matches between none of them?

Comment: exactly, the row must have no duplicates, column A is the roster, and each column beyond is a match opponent, each column from B -> is a match for the players in Col A